# didSelectRowAtIndexPath returning a very large number

Tags: swift, didselectrowatindexpath

Trying to find the row number touched in a TableViewController using:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell?;
    NSLog("Current Cell = %d", currentCell!)
}
```

It returns the same number if you press the same cell but comes up with extremely large numbers like 410772272 or 409747056. In a two cell test I was expecting a 1 or 2. Returns the same numbers if you use a %i or %d.

Any insights or am I using the wrong call completely.

Comment: `currentCell!` is a *pointer* to a table view cell ... Did you mean `NSLog("Current row = %d", indexPath.row)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
NSLog("Current Cell = %d", currentCell!)
```

you are printing the memory address which is stored in the `currentCell` variable - that is why it is such a high number.

You can get the row number via `indexPath.row`; you don't even need the `let currentCell =` line.

Comment: Indeed, the syntax appears to be:

NSLog("Current Row = %i", indexPath!.row)